# Want Double Tapped Image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 100 images which are stored in the array and displayed in single imageview randomly using `swipe gesture.`

On double tapping I want to store that particular image in `NSUserDefault`. Can anyone please help me in achieving this.

I tried this

```
randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

int padding=0;

CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

[ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

[scrollView addSubview:ImgView];

[ImgView setAccessibilityIdentifier:[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(@"") forKey:@""];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587453/filtering-single-and-double-taps

Comment: What have you tried? Questions must show some research has been carried out and this shows none also your question is doesn't provide much information to what you actually want.

Comment: you can set tag to each one image. for example image.tag = rndNumb. rndNumb = 1..100 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `-viewDidLoad` add UITapGestureRecognizer to your image.
You need to enable user interaction on the `UIImageView` which in set to `NO` by default.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Default.png", @"Default2.png", @"Default3.png", nil];
    NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [imgArray count];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    NSString *strImgName = [imgArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber];
    [self.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImgName]];
    NSLog(@"Image Name = %@", strImgName);
    [self.imgView setTag:randomNumber];

    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.imgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

And then add the @selector to handle the double tap as follows:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    int imgViewTag = [gesture.view tag];
    NSString *strImageName = [imgArray objectAtIndex:imgViewTag];
    NSLog(@"Selected Image = %@",strImageName);
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:strImageName forKey:@"imageName"];
}
```

[Sample Project Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii6owy3kezi1mma/ST-16647964.zip)

Comment: @Jitendra You need to get the image name from `NSString *fullImageName` variable

Comment: how may get the douuble tapped image.

Comment: @JitendraDeore set the image tag like this `[ImgView setTag:randIdx];`

Comment: @JitendraDeore Please check the sample dropbox link.

Comment: @JitendraDeore Did you check the sample project, is it what you want?

Comment: i want to fetch randomly genrated doubble tapped image.

Comment: @JitendraDeore Thats what I have done. `NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [imgArray count];` in my code create a random number

Answer (score 0):

You can add UITapGestureRecognizer to your image in viewDidLoad like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

     UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
     [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureTap];
     gestureTap.delegate = self;
     gestureTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

     [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureTap];
}
```

And then in gesture's action, you can save image to NSUserDefault like this

```
 -(void)doubleTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.imageView.image forKey:@"imagesaved"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 }
```

Comment: i want only doubble tapped image out of 100 single doubble tapped image require.

Comment: @ajay self.imageView.image wont get you the name of the image.

Comment: how to get the image name and how may i display that image ti imageview.

Comment: @Jitendra, You can find it in same way as you write in your code above

Comment: Is FrontsCards a array which contain set of image name?

Comment: Then what is the problem? You have code in swipe's action in which you select one image randomly so you have to save randIdx and then in gesture's action save image like this:
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx] forKey:@"imagesaved"];

Answer (score 0):

You can may try like this:

Displaying:

```
  YourMethod {

    randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

    NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

    NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

    int padding=0;

    CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

    ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

    [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedAction:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    [ImgView setTag:randIndx];
    [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];
```

}

Storing ...

```
  -(void)tappedAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
  {
   // storing in nsuserdefault ...
    int indArr = [sender.view tag];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([sender.view image]);
    NSString *thKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indArr];
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:theKey];
```

}

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation(@"") forKey:@""];   what i pass here.

Comment: get o index every time indArr.

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)