# prevent touchdown IBAction event from firing when UITapGestureRecognizer fires on double tap

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gesture

I have two `IBActions` applied to a button one of which fires on *touchdown* and *down* and the other on *touch up*, however I also have a tap gesture applied to the button that fires on a *double tap*.

I've applied `NSLog` to see whats happening and the result is that both the *touchdown* and *double tap* fire when I double tap (fortunately the *touch up* doesn't fire) which makes sense - but how do i prevent the touch down firing when I double tap?

Code example

```
//fired on touch down 
-(IBAction)touchdown:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"touching down.");
}

//fired on touch up
-(IBAction)touchup:(id)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"taking off.");
}

//fired on double click
-(IBAction)boost:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"goodbye.");
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code so we can help you in a better way

Comment: post your code to understanding the problem

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587453/filtering-single-and-double-taps can help you

Comment: I've added my example code these are all linked to buttons and gestures within the storyboard.

Comment: You need to implement this method, - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch

Comment: @karthika would you be able to edit the code above to show how this would be implemented?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Import the delegate, `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

I think you done this in viewDidLoad Method,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(boost:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

You need to implement this delegate method, based on your touch down coordinates,

```
  -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
        CGPoint coords = [touch locationInView:self.button];
        NSLog(@"Coords: %g, %g", coords.x, coords.y);
        if (coords.y < 21 && coords.y > 25)
           return NO;
        else
           return YES;
    }
```